# installed imagick not seen by php_info

Tags: php, imagick

I am not very experienced on linux, and need help here.
I have installed ImageMagick, and you can see the version below:

```
[root@zpanel temp]# convert -version

Version: ImageMagick 6.8.5-4 2013-05-02 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2013 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib fontconfig freetype jng jp2 jpeg lcms png ps tiff x xml zlib
```

But I cannot see it in my php_info(check url : http://www.galepress.com/phpinfo.php). I have restarted httpd etc, but no good.
ps : I have also run the following command and get the warnings:

```
[root@zpanel temp]# php -m | grep imagick

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/src/imagick-3.0.1/modules/imagick.so' - libMagickWand.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: ImageMagick and Imagick are not the same. The first one is a standalone program, the second one a PHP extension. It seems that you have installed ImageMagick and then tried to load Imagick in your php.ini file.

Comment: thank you for this. should i enable Imagick now? how can i do that?

Comment: If it's available for your Linux distro you should be able to find it in whatever package manager it uses. Otherwise, you'll have to  [compile it yourself](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to use Imagick class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887372/unable-to-use-imagick-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to install *php5-imagick* package on Debian:

```
apt-get install php5-imagick
```

In case of dependencies problem you may need to try installing the older version:

```
apt-get install php5-imagick/oldstable
```

If everything goes well, don't forget to restart the Apache service:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install ImageMagick for php environment.

So, for now you have installed ImageMagick only in Linux

Comment: how do you install for php?