# Unable to use Imagick class

Tags: php, wampserver, imagick

I have installed imagick version:6.8.6-7 on my PC
Operating system:Windows 7 32-bit

Now i want to use Imagick for my PHP project.I am using Wampserver which provides me *PHP version:5.3.10*.So i also installed a **.dll** file,made changes in php.ini,verified if the path is set with php_info() before using Imagick class and everything was ok.

Problem description:
I wrote the script to test if i can use Imagick.Following is the script:

```
<?PHP
function alist ($array) {  //This function prints a text array as an html list.
$alist = "<ul>";
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
  $alist .= "<li>$array[$i]";
}
$alist .= "</ul>";
return $alist;
}
exec("convert -version", $out, $rcode); //Try to get ImageMagick "convert" program version number.
echo "Version return code is $rcode <br>"; //Print the return code: 0 if OK, nonzero if error.
echo alist($out); //Print the output of "convert -version"

if(class_exists("imagick") )
{
echo "Ready to use Imagick class";
}
else
{
echo "Cannot use Imagick class";
}
?>
```

**Output**

```
Version return code is 0

    Version: ImageMagick 6.8.6-7 2013-07-23 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
    Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2013 ImageMagick Studio LLC
    Features: DPC OpenMP
    Delegates: bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jng jp2 jpeg lcms lzma openexr pango png ps tiff x xml zlib

Cannot use Imagick class
```

So even if the Version is properly displayed,i am not able to use Imagick class.How to fix this,help

Answer (score 1):

1: Install ImageMagick software [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)

2: Download pecl-5.2-dev.zip (choose the version relevant to your PHP) from http://snaps.php.net/

3: Copy php_imagick.dll from the archive you've downloaded to your PHP extention folder.

4: Add the following line to php.ini (in the exntentions section):
extension=php_imagick.dll

5: Restart your server

Answer (score 0):

cmorrissey's link for 2) seems to be broken but dlls can be downloaded [here](https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.1.2/windows).

If you get a "CORE_RL_wand_.dll is missing" error, the solution is [here](https://github.com/WPN-XM/WPN-XM/issues/222). In my case, I had to take all the "CORE" dlls from the ImageMagic installation folder and copy them into the /php folder.